# jQuery b is undefined during animate callback

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I'm making a slider and this is the meat of my code;

```
$('#slider a').click(function () {
                elem.filter(this.hash).addClass("active").animate({"right":"0"}, 3000, 
                    function() {
                        elem.filter(activeElem).removeClass("active");
                        activeElem = elem.filter(this.hash);
                    });
```

I'm trying to remove the class "active" from the existing viewable element, then adding "active" to the new element.  Yet, when I run it, I get a an error in Firebug sayed, "b is undefined" and in IE that "nodeType is null or not an object".

Can you not set variables in a callback function?

Comment: you need to post some HTML & JS (which is incomplete). How about http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.com ??

Comment: Avinash is right.  You need to post more code.  Is `elem` a set of elements, defined somewhere above?  Where is `activeElem` defined?  Post the full code and you might have better luck getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing `activeElem` as a jQuery object anyway, you can simplify your code and remove the *probably* offending [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) check, like this:

```
$('#slider a').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass("active").animate({"right":"0"}, 3000, function() {
      activeElem.removeClass("active");
      activeElem = $(this);
   });
});
```

I can't say for sure what your error on the filter check is currently without seeing how you're initializing the collections, but since you're storing it as a jQuery element anyway, and `.hash` denotes an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) the above should be a much simpler solution...or if there's only one `.active` class element, just do this:

```
$('#slider a').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass("active").animate({"right":"0"}, 3000, function() {
      $(".active").not(this).removeClass("active");
   });
});
```